# Is their a way to create Dummy Response with 500 code in HTTParty

Tags: ruby, httparty

Here my HTTParty code

```
      response = HTTParty.post(api_url,body: form_data,timeout: 5)
      rescue Timeout::Error
      ## create dummy response with 500 error code
      response = HTTParty::Response.new()
      ensure
       response
```

all I'm trying to do is ensure If the HTTParty is unable to connect the given website create a dummy response body objec

But when I try to create a dummy Response object like this

```
     ## response = HTTParty::Response.new(Rack::Request.new(api_url),Rack::Response.new('TimeOut Error',500),'TimeOutError')
```

but this does not work because my response object does not respond_to [`to_hash`](http://rdoc.info/github/jnunemaker/httparty/HTTParty/Response:initialize)

Can anyone suggest a better way to accomplish the same

Comment: What are you hoping for? You could respond with a JSON object that can be converted to a `Hash` using `JSON.parse` but your post is a little confusing

Comment: All I want is to create a dummy  HTTParty Response object if the HTTParty response get time out.

Answer (score 15):

In case anybody comes looking after 4 years, one could try the following:

```
httparty_req = HTTParty::Request.new Net::HTTP::Get, '/'
nethttp_resp = Net::HTTPInternalServerError.new('1.1', 500, 'Internal Server Error')
response = HTTParty::Response.new(httparty_req, nethttp_resp, lambda {''}, body: '')
```

Comment: 8 years later I now ant to know how to do it without out an error and a successful response.

Comment: `httparty_req = HTTParty::Request.new Net::HTTP::Get, '/'  
 nethttp_resp = Net::HTTPOK.new(1.0, "200", "OK")`  
`response = HTTParty::Response.new(httparty_req, nethttp_resp, lambda {''}, body: '')`